# Xdebug 3.0 WSL2 and VSCode - Configuration That Works

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-remote

Most examples on the web for getting PHP debugging working with VSCode and WSL use Xdebug 2.x php.ini settings.  Those no longer work with version 3.0.  See the [Xdebug Upgrade](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) for details on changes.

The following worked for me on a PHP project with a single file just to test debugging.  Using Ubuntu 20.04, WSL2, Xdebug 3.02 with the VSCode extensions Remote WSL and PHP Debug by Felix Becker.

I had to modify both `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` on my system.  Hope this works for you folks.

php.ini

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension = ./lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger 
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.client_port = 9003
```

launch.json

```json
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": 
            {
                "/var/www/html/test": "${workspaceRoot}"             
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 9):

To supplement what [@Jim D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66190658/) has documented:

I had originally opened my VSCode WSL2 workspace using its Windows network share path `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\srv\www\myphpwebsite`. *Xdebug* did **not** work with this configuration—presumably because port 9003 was not being forwarded from Windows to WSL2.

I had to **reopen** the workspace/folder using the [Remote - WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl). To do this, you can click the *Remote-WSL* control on the VSCode status bar (bottom left corner) and choose "Reopen Folder in WSL". It took about 10 minutes to "install" Remote-WSL into WSL2.

[image: Remote-WSL control]

Thereafter, I had to "install" (or enable) the [PHP Debug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) specifically in the *WSL:Ubuntu* WSL2 environment, even though it was already installed in VSCode.

[image: PHP Debug extension enabled in WSL2]

My `launch.json` configuration is:

```json
        {
            "name": "myphpwebsite",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/srv/www/myphpwebsite": "${workspaceRoot}" 
            },
            //"stopOnEntry": true,
            //"log": true,
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 10000,
                //"show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 250,
                "max_depth": 10
            }
        },
```

My PHP configuration (for PHP 7.3) is as follows: In the `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d` folder, the `20-xdebug.ini` file is a symbolic link to `/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/xdebug.ini`. This was configured automatically via `sudo apt install php7.3-xdebug`. It contains just:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

Then I added a supplemental `99-xdebug.ini` file to the `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d` folder (to ensure it loads after the `20-xdebug.ini` file, and to keep its configuration separate from the distro). That file contains:

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
;xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
;xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.output_dir=/tmp/xdebug/
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
xdebug.var_display_max_children=250
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after making `.ini` changes.

With the `xdebug.start_with_request=trigger` setting, after launching the debugger in VSCode, I use the Chrome [Xdebug helper extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) to trigger an XDebug session. (If the `.ini` setting `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` is used instead, then the *Xdebug helper* extension is not needed, since Xdebug will try to connect with a debugger on port 9003 with *every* web request to PHP.)

Lastly, I commented out the `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log` setting, since this produces very large verbose logs. (But it was useful in initially diagnosing what was happening.)

## UPDATE

To use `xdebug.start_with_request=trigger` and `xdebug.trigger_value=VSCODE` with VSCode's "Launch currently open script" debug configuration, I had to set the correct environment variables in an `"env"` section in `launch.json`:

```json
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/srv/www/myphpwebsite": "${workspaceRoot}" 
            },
            //"stopOnEntry": true,
            //"log": true,
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug",
                "XDEBUG_TRIGGER": "VSCODE"
            }
        },
```

Good luck with Xdebugging!

Comment: Do you have a documentation link for the change to `env`? GitHub docs still indicate it's `env`: https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug#supported-launchjson-settings. See "Options specific to CLI debugging" there.

Answer (score 0):

Update for PHP 8.1. Needed to change the full path to the xdebug.so file.  zend_extension = ...   Your path may be different,depending on your system.  It is the "20210902" that is different.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20210902/xdebug.so
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps
Install WSL 2 and Ubuntu 22.04

```
wsl --install
```

Open Ubuntu Terminal and Install Debug

```
sudo apt install -y php-xdebug
```

Edit **xdebug.ini** and add the lines

```
vim /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = develop,debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
```

Create a project folder:

mkdir ~/demo
cd ~/demo

In VS Code
Install the WSL extension like this:

Press F1, press Backspace, paste the following command and press Enter:

```
ext install ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
```

Install the PHP Debug extension like this:

Press F1, press Backspace, paste the following command and press Enter:

```
ext install xdebug.php-debug
```

Open the project folder in WSL like this:

Press F1, enter WSL: Connect to WSL and press Enter
Select the folder demo
Create the file ~/demo/.vscode/launch.json with the following contents:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

Open the file index.php

Set a breakpoint on the second line

Press F5 to start debugging

In your web browser
Install “Xdebug helper” extension

[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc)

Go to http://localhost:8080/

Click the extension’s icon and enable it

Reload the page

The breakpoint should now be hit.

[Original Post](https://www.clausconrad.com/notes/r.dev.php.vscode-wsl2-xdebug3/)