# Trying to use xdebug w/ Win10 WSL2 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 with VSCode, xdebug is listening but not connecting?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug

Relevant environment info:
Windows 10
WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04.3
PHP 8.0
xdebug 3.1.3

hello, I'm trying to get debugging in vscode set up for php. I've follow the following steps:
1.) following the steps from the [xdebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard)
2.) installed the [PHP Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug) extension in vscode on WSL.
3.) compared settings to those in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190658/xdebug-3-0-wsl2-and-vscode-configuration-that-works)

When I try to run and debug by listening for Xdebug, the following is the output:

```
<- outputEvent
OutputEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'output',
  body: {
    category: 'stdout',
    output: 'Listening to Xdebug on port 0.0.0.0:9003 ...\n'
  }
}

Listening to Xdebug on port 0.0.0.0:9003 ...
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true
}
<- outputEvent
OutputEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'output',
  body: { category: 'stdout', output: '\n' }
}
```

and then nothing happens. the PHP script doesn't run, no breakpoints are hit, etc.

The following is the relevant portion of my `launch.json`:

```
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "stopOnEntry": true,
      "log": true,
      "pathMappings": 
      {
          "/var/www/html/test": "${workspaceRoot}"  ,
          "/mnt/c/Cody": "C:\\Cody"           
      },
      "env": {
        "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
        "XDEBUG_TRIGGER": "VSCODE",
        "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
      }
    },
```

The following is my `20-xdebug.ini` file:

```
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger 
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
```

The following is the output of `phpinfo()` if of interest:

```
PHP Version => 8.0.17

System => Linux [computer name] 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64
Build Date => Mar 20 2022 17:04:09
Build System => Linux
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gmp.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pspell.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini

PHP API => 20200930
PHP Extension => 20200930
Zend Extension => 420200930
Zend Extension Build => API420200930,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20200930,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => available, disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, convert.iconv.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v4.0.17, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.17, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 8.0.17

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20200930 => /usr/lib/php/20200930
file_uploads => On => On
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/share/php => .:/usr/share/php
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => -1 => -1
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision => -1 => -1
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
syslog.facility => LOG_USER => LOG_USER
syslog.filter => no-ctrl => no-ctrl
syslog.ident => php => php
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => -1 => -1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.exception_ignore_args => On => On
zend.exception_string_param_max_len => 0 => 0
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
zend.signal_check => Off => Off

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.68.0
Age => 5
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => Yes
HTTP2 => Yes
GSSAPI => Yes
KERBEROS5 => Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS => Yes
PSL => Yes
HTTPS_PROXY => Yes
MULTI_SSL => No
BROTLI => Yes
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.1.1f
ZLib Version => 1.2.11
libSSH Version => libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
curl.cainfo => no value => no value


xdebug

[1m__   __   _      _                 
[1m\ \ / /  | |    | |                
[1m \ V / __| | ___| |__  _   _  __ _ 
[1m  > < / _` |/ _ \ '_ \| | | |/ _` |
[1m / . \ (_| |  __/ |_) | |_| | (_| |
[1m/_/ \_\__,_|\___|_.__/ \__,_|\__, |
[1m                              __/ |
[1m                             |___/ 

[0mVersion => 3.1.3
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

             Enabled Features (through 'xdebug.mode' setting)             
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Helpers => ✘ disabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

                            Optional Features                            
Compressed File Support => yes (gzip)
Clock Source => clock_gettime

Debugger => enabled
IDE Key =>  

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => 0.0.0.0 => 0.0.0.0
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.coverage_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.log => /tmp/xdebug_remote.log => /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => debug => debug
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.start_with_request => trigger => trigger
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.use_compression => 1 => 1
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.13

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlrpc

XMLRPC extension version => 1.0.0RC3
core library version => xmlrpc-epi v. 0.54
author => Dan Libby
homepage => http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by => Epinions.com

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

xsl

XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.34
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.9.10
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 1.1.34

Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching => Disabled
Optimization => Disabled
SHM Cache => Enabled
File Cache => Disabled
JIT => On
Startup Failed => Opcode Caching is disabled for CLI

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename => no value => no value
opcache.consistency_checks => 0 => 0
opcache.dups_fix => Off => Off
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off
opcache.enable_file_override => Off => Off
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks => On => On
opcache.file_cache_only => Off => Off
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.force_restart_timeout => 180 => 180
opcache.huge_code_pages => Off => Off
opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 8 => 8
opcache.jit => tracing => tracing
opcache.jit_bisect_limit => 0 => 0
opcache.jit_blacklist_root_trace => 16 => 16
opcache.jit_blacklist_side_trace => 8 => 8
opcache.jit_buffer_size => 0 => 0
opcache.jit_debug => 0 => 0
opcache.jit_hot_func => 127 => 127
opcache.jit_hot_loop => 64 => 64
opcache.jit_hot_return => 8 => 8
opcache.jit_hot_side_exit => 8 => 8
opcache.jit_max_exit_counters => 8192 => 8192
opcache.jit_max_loop_unrolls => 8 => 8
opcache.jit_max_polymorphic_calls => 2 => 2
opcache.jit_max_recursive_calls => 2 => 2
opcache.jit_max_recursive_returns => 2 => 2
opcache.jit_max_root_traces => 1024 => 1024
opcache.jit_max_side_traces => 128 => 128
opcache.jit_prof_threshold => 0.005 => 0.005
opcache.lockfile_path => /tmp => /tmp
opcache.log_verbosity_level => 1 => 1
opcache.max_accelerated_files => 10000 => 10000
opcache.max_file_size => 0 => 0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage => 5 => 5
opcache.memory_consumption => 128 => 128
opcache.opt_debug_level => 0 => 0
opcache.optimization_level => 0 => 0x7FFEBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model => no value => no value
opcache.preload => no value => no value
opcache.preload_user => no value => no value
opcache.protect_memory => Off => Off
opcache.record_warnings => Off => Off
opcache.restrict_api => no value => no value
opcache.revalidate_freq => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.save_comments => On => On
opcache.use_cwd => On => On
opcache.validate_permission => Off => Off
opcache.validate_root => Off => Off
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On


Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable => Value
SHELL => /bin/bash
COLORTERM => truecolor
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION => 1.65.2
WSL_DISTRO_NAME => Ubuntu
NAME => [computer name]
PWD => [pwd]
LOGNAME => cdegen
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE => []
HOME => [home]
LANG => C.UTF-8
WSL_INTEROP => /run/WSL/12_interop
LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
GIT_ASKPASS => /home/cdegen/.vscode-server/bin/c722ca6c7eed3d7987c0d5c3df5c45f6b15e77d1/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS =>  
LESSCLOSE => /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
TERM => xterm-256color
LESSOPEN => | /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER => [user]
VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE => /tmp/vscode-git-7b47f41904.sock
SHLVL => 1
WSLENV => VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/up
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN => []
XDG_DATA_DIRS => /usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH => [path]
HOSTTYPE => x86_64
TERM_PROGRAM => vscode
VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI => /tmp/vscode-ipc-b2629323-b536-4def-bba8-5a4b7269f2f6.sock
_ => /usr/bin/php
OLDPWD => [oldpwd]

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
$_SERVER['SHELL'] => /bin/bash
$_SERVER['COLORTERM'] => truecolor
$_SERVER['TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION'] => 1.65.2
$_SERVER['WSL_DISTRO_NAME'] => Ubuntu
$_SERVER['NAME'] => [name]
$_SERVER['PWD'] => [pwd]
$_SERVER['LOGNAME'] => [logname]
$_SERVER['VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE'] => [logname]
$_SERVER['HOME'] => [home]
$_SERVER['LANG'] => C.UTF-8
$_SERVER['WSL_INTEROP'] => /run/WSL/12_interop
$_SERVER['LS_COLORS'] => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
$_SERVER['GIT_ASKPASS'] => /home/cdegen/.vscode-server/bin/c722ca6c7eed3d7987c0d5c3df5c45f6b15e77d1/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh
$_SERVER['VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS'] => 
$_SERVER['LESSCLOSE'] => /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
$_SERVER['TERM'] => xterm-256color
$_SERVER['LESSOPEN'] => | /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
$_SERVER['USER'] => [user]
$_SERVER['VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE'] => /tmp/vscode-git-7b47f41904.sock
$_SERVER['SHLVL'] => 1
$_SERVER['WSLENV'] => VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/up
$_SERVER['VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN'] => []
$_SERVER['XDG_DATA_DIRS'] => /usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
$_SERVER['PATH'] => []
$_SERVER['HOSTTYPE'] => x86_64
$_SERVER['TERM_PROGRAM'] => vscode
$_SERVER['VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI'] => /tmp/vscode-ipc-b2629323-b536-4def-bba8-5a4b7269f2f6.sock
$_SERVER['_'] => /usr/bin/php
$_SERVER['OLDPWD'] => [oldpwd]
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] => test.php
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] => test.php
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] => test.php
$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'] => test.php
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] => 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] => 1648655324.4991
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] => 1648655324
$_SERVER['argv'] => Array
(
    [0] => test.php
)

$_SERVER['argc'] => 1
```

There are no settings in my `php.ini` file that are relevant to xdebug to my knowledge.
I have updated my environment variables to include `XDEBUG_SESSION=1` as suggested [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#activate_debugger)
I believe have checked my firewall settings correctly and port 9003 is open (per [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/faq)). I've tried messing around with other port numbers as well.

I feel the answer should be something simple that I'm overlooking, but I'm utterly stumped by this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run the server and install an xdebug extension on the browser,
so, in the typical debugging session, you will have:

1. Xdebug configuration running on vscode.
2. your development server running /or/ apache if you are using it.
3. Xdebug extension on the browser set to (**Debug**).

That way, it will work fine when you set a breakpoint on VS code.